# Basis for polynomial ring modulo polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $k$ be a field and consider polynomials $g_i\in k[X_i]\subseteq k[X_1,\dots, X_n]$ for $1\leq i\leq n$ of degree $d_i\geq 1$. Let
$$V:=\frac{k[X_1,\dots,X_n]}{(g_1,\dots,g_n)}.$$

My goal is to formally prove that $V$ is a vector space over $k$ of dimension $d_1\cdots d_n$ with basis $\mathcal B$ given by elements of the form $X_1^{k_1}\cdots X_n^{k_n}$, with $0\leq k_i<d_i$.

The way I prove it is to firstly prove that every $f\in k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ can be written as $f=\sum_{i=1}^nq_ig_i+R$ for $q_i,R\in k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ with $\deg_{X_i}R<d_i$ for every $1\leq i\leq n$. This already shows that $\mathcal B$ spans $V$, and now one only needs to argue that the elements of $\mathcal B$ are linearly independent.

However, this feels a little too complicated, especially considering how intuitive the claim is. I am wondering if there is another way to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most efficient way would be to prove a slightly more general statement, which can be proven by induction in a very straightforward way.

Namely, let $P(n)$ be the assertion "for every commutative ring $R$, and any polynomials $g_i\in R[X_i]\subseteq R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ of degree $d_i\geq 1$, the quotient ring $V=R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(g_1,\ldots,g_n)$ is a free $R$-module of rank $d_1\cdots d_n$ with basis $X_1^{k_1}\cdots X_n^{k_n}$, where $0\leq k_i<d_i$ for all $i$."

The statement $P(1)$ is straightforward to prove, and I think you know how to do it.

So assume that $P(n-1)$ holds for some $n>1$. Then we have
$$
V=R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(g_1,\ldots,g_n)\cong(R[X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}]/(g_1,\ldots,g_{n-1}))[X_n]/(g_n).
$$
Now by $P(1)$ applied to the commutative ring $R[X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}]/(g_1,\ldots,g_{n-1}))$, this is a free $R[X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}]/(g_1,\ldots,g_{n-1}))$-module of rank $d_n$ with basis $(X_n^{k_n})_{0\leq k_n< d_n}$. But then by $P(n-1)$, the quotient $R[X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}]/(g_1,\ldots,g_{n-1}))$ is a free $R$-module with basis $(X_1^{k_1}\cdots X_{n-1}^{k_{n-1}})_{\forall i:\ 0\leq k_i<d_i}$.

To conclude, I leave it to you to verify that if you have maps between commutative rings $A\to B\to C$ such that $B$ is a free $A$-module with basis $b_1,\ldots,b_r$ and $C$ is a free $B$-module with basis $c_1,\ldots,c_s$, then $C$ is a free $A$-module with basis $(b_ic_j)_{\substack{1\leq i\leq r\\1\leq j\leq s}}$.